# I want to clamp each instance of the same prefab to the y axis only

Tags: unity, 2d, mobile

I instantiated the prefab "paddle" twice then I tried clamping it to the y-axis only; using Mathf.Clamp, however, the min and max values end up being applied to both instances of "paddle" and hence they can move in the x-axis

ok so I'm trying to make a 2d mobile pong game, I have a prefab "paddle" which are the rackets/bats which the balls collide with.

I instantiated the same prefab twice one on each side of the screen :

```
Paddle paddle1 = Instantiate(Paddle) as Paddle;
Paddle paddle2 = Instantiate(Paddle) as Paddle;
paddle2.Init(true); //right paddle
paddle1.Init(false); //left paddle
```

Now i want each of the paddles to only be able to move in the y axis (UP And DOWN).

So I tried clamping them with:

```
var poss = transform.position;
poss.x =  Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -1.0f, 1.0f);
transform.position = poss;
```

However, this caused the left paddle to still be able to move to the right and the right paddle to be able to the left( I don't want them to move in the axis at all).

This is the file GameManager.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Ball Ball;

    public Paddle Paddle;

    public static Vector2 topRight;
    public static Vector2 bottomLeft;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() 
    {
        bottomLeft = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2 (0,0));
        topRight = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2 
        (Screen.width,Screen.height));

        Instantiate(Ball); 

        //Paddle paddle1 = Instantiate(Paddle) as Paddle;
        Paddle paddle1 = Instantiate(Paddle) as Paddle;
        Paddle paddle2 = Instantiate(Paddle) as Paddle;
        paddle2.Init(true); //right paddle
        paddle1.Init(false); //left paddle
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

}
```

This is the file paddle.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Paddle : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    float directionY;
    float speed;
    float height;

    float distance;
    string input;  
    bool isRight;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        height = transform.localScale.y;
        speed=5f;   
    }

    public void Init(bool isRightPaddle)
    {
        isRight = isRightPaddle;
        Vector2 pos = Vector2.zero;

        if(isRightPaddle)
        {
            //Place paddle on the right of the screen
            pos = new Vector2(GameManager.topRight.x, 0);
            pos -= Vector2.right * transform.localScale.x; //Move a bit to the left
        }
        else 
        {
            //Place paddle on the left of the screen
            pos = new Vector2(GameManager.bottomLeft.x, 0);
            pos += Vector2.right * transform.localScale.x; //Move a bit to the right
        } 

        //Update this paddle's position
        transform.position = pos;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var poss = transform.position;
        poss.x =  Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -8.0f, 8.0f);
        transform.position = poss; 
    }
}
```

I expect each paddle to not be able to move in the x axis. Only in the y axis

c# unity3d mobile

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: you are updating the x position value while you want to update the y value.

Please have a look at this part of your code:

```js
        var poss = transform.position;
        poss.x =  Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -8.0f, 8.0f);
        transform.position = poss;
```

What you're doing here is telling Unity:

> At every frame, (line 1) I want you to get the position of my transform, (line 2) update and clamp the x value of my position to be contained between -8.0 and 8.0 but don't touch any other values, (line 3) set the position with the clamped x value as the new position of my transform.

This code will let your paddle moving on x (left / right) from -8.0 to 8.0 values. In  Unity, by default, left/right axis is x, up/down is y, and forward/back is z. If you want your paddle to only move on Y when you press up and down arrow, you just have to only update the Y value of their `transform.position` and clamp it to the min / max values you need while forcing the default x and z values that you need.